# Creating graph with date and time in ticklabels with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, plot, time-series

I have my data in an array of the following structure,

```py
[[1293606162197, 0, 0],
 [1293605477994, 63, 0],
 [1293605478057, 0, 0],
 [1293605478072, 2735, 1249],
 [1293606162213, 0, 0],
 [1293606162229, 0, 0]]
```

The first column is epoch time (in `ms`), second is `y1` and third is `y2`. I need a plot with the time on the x-axis, and `y1` and `y2` on left and right y-axes.

I have been scouring through the documentation but couldn't find any way to get my x-axis ticks to display both date and time, like "28/12 16:48", i.e., "date/month hour:min". All the documentation helps me with is to display dates alone, but that is not what I want.

It is actually a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468921/reading-and-graphing-data-read-from-huge-files).

Comment: Should the X-axis represent real linear time or you need just the 'DD/MM HH:MM' text under each tick that has data?

Comment: I want the absolute date, which will need to be displayed vertically, as it won't fit horizontally.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I hope this helps.  I've always had a hard time with matplotlib's dates.  Matplotlib requires a [float format](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html) which is days since epoch.  The helper functions `num2date` and `date2num` along with python builtin `datetime` can be used to convert to/from.  The formatting business was lifted from [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html) example.  You can change an axis on any plot to a date axis using `set_major_formatter`.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
import datetime

a = np.array([
    [1293605162197, 0, 0],
    [1293605477994, 63, 0],
    [1293605478057, 0, 0],
    [1293605478072, 2735, 1249],
    [1293606162213, 0, 0],
    [1293606162229, 0, 0]])

d = a[:,0]
y1 = a[:,1]
y2 = a[:,2]

# convert epoch to matplotlib float format
s = d/1000
ms = d-1000*s  # not needed?
dts = map(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp, s)
fds = dates.date2num(dts) # converted

# matplotlib date format object
hfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d %H:%M')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.vlines(fds, y2, y1)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MinuteLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.3)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: If you use a really large dataset, you probably want to call any plot functions after you call ax.xaxis.set_major_locator() otherwise you may run into an "RuntimeError: RRuleLocator" which you could avoid.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of matplotlib (e.g. 3.7.0), there's no need to explicitly convert date to numbers, matplotlib handles it internally. So simply passing the datetime objects as x-values works.

To show custom ticks, `DateFormatter` along with `MinuteLocator`/`MicrosecondLocator` etc. (depending on the resolution of the time component) can be used.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

data = [[1293606162197, 0, 0], [1293605477994, 63, 0], [1293605478057, 0, 0], 
        [1293605478072, 2735, 1249], [1293606162213, 0, 0], [1293606162229, 0, 0]]

# sort time-series by datetime
x, y1, y2 = zip(*sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0]))

# convert to datetime objects
x = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i / 1000) for i in x]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y1, label='y1');       # plot y1 series
ax.plot(x, y2, label='y2')        # plot y2 series
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m %H:%M'))  # format date/time
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=2))       # show every second minute
ax.legend()                                                        # show legend
fig.autofmt_xdate();                                               # format ticklabels
```

[image: img]

If you don't particularly care how datetime is shown as x-ticks, there `matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter` that does "pretty" formatting for you. For the example at hand, that would look like:

```py
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(x, y1, label='y1');       # plot y1 series
ax.plot(x, y2, label='y2')        # plot y2 series

locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator))  # format date/time
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)                                 # show every second minute
ax.legend();
```

[image: img2]