# Matplotlib: plotting time seconds are floats

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I have created a couple of graphs using matplotlib.
X-axis always contains time and Y-axis a given value.

The graphs were created as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Experience Graph')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Experience')
ax.plot(self.timeStorage, teamTotalXP)
ax.fill_between(self.timeStorage,0, teamTotalXP, alpha=0.5)
...
plt.xticks(rotation=20)
plt.savefig(directory + "teams_experience.svg")
plt.clf()
```

With timestorage being created like this:

```
timeStorage.append(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(replay.info.game_time))
```

I tried this on 2 different Ubuntu implementations:

Ubuntu 1:
[image: The graph I like]

Ubuntu 2:
[image: The graoh I do not like]

As can be seen my second version has annoying floats as seconds.

Extra information:

- Both are run on Ubuntu 13.10
- I use the same python and gcc versions in both systems (python 2.7.5+ and gcc 4.8.1)
- matplotlib version differs !! My first version is within 1.2.1, second one is 1.3.1.
  -> I think this is what causes my problem but downgrading my matplotlib build seems stupid...

Therefor I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix my problem or if downgrading is the only solution.

Thanks in advance,

Giriel

Comment: does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500441/pandas-datetime-with-julian-day/20500819#20500819  I'm not at a machine where I can put an example together for you, but I think that all you need is to specify a custom datetime formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the DateFormatter.
Strange that I did not have to do this before.

Look at this answer for more information:
[How to change date format using matplolib in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911987/how-to-change-date-format-using-matplolib-in-python)