# Counting total values per month while plotting only yearly labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame :

```
                         H     T       date
date                                       
1990-08-26 11:30:00   38.0  11.6 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00   63.0  11.3 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00   87.0  10.9 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00  111.0  10.6 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00  134.0  10.4 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00  154.0  10.1 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00  178.0   9.9 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00  205.0   9.6 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00  233.0   9.4 1990-08-26
1990-08-26 11:30:00  260.0   9.2 1990-08-26
```

Where T is temperature and H is height in meters. 
I want to count how many days are in each month ( and in each year) and then do this as a bar plot. 
So what I do is the following ( the code is below)

```
df = pd.read_csv('/radiosonde_Iceland_analysis.   
/data/H_T_series_1991_2016',sep = "\t")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
df['date'] = df.index.date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
print(df.head(10))
  df_count=df.groupby([df.date.dt.year,df.date.dt.month,df.date.dt.day]).count()
df_count=df_count[df_count['date']>1991]
print(df_count)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Nr of observations(vertical points) per   
year')   
df_count['H'].plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,width=0.6,colormap='Paired',alpha=0.7)
plt.savefig('count_heights_ave_1991_2016.png',dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

First, how can I get the total number of ocurences of T for each month ? What I get is something like:

1992 1    2     2113  2111  2113
          4     2148  2146  2148
          5     2028  2027  2028
          12    2044  2042  2044
          19    2361  2361  2361
          21    2061  2061  2061
          22    2014  2014  2014
          23    2008  2008  2008
          24    2161  2161  2161
          27    2024  2023  2024
          29    2374  2373  2374
     4    3     2025  2024  2025
1995 7    11    2009  2009  2009
2006 1    1     4593  4593  4593
          2     4870  4870  4870
          3     4249  4249  4249
          4     4761  4761  4761
          5     4889  4889  4889
          6     2380  2380  2380
          7     4504  4504  4504
          8     4828  4828  4828
          9     4933  4933  4933
but I would like the monthly totals.

Second,  I would want the years on the x axis labels but since the index is defined as yy-mm-dd-hh etc I get all the labels crammed in there ( as in the figure attached - is all black as you can see). 
Can you please tell me what is the way to plot those axes correctly and only have tick marks for years ( not for the months).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some test data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(444)

start = '1990-01-01'
end = '2017-12-31'
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='30min')

# different number of repeats per 30-min tick
rpt = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=idx.size)
idx = np.repeat(idx, rpt)
df = pd.DataFrame({'T': np.random.randn(idx.size)}, index=idx)
df['date'] = df.index.date
df.index.name = 'date'
```

Snippet:

```
>>> df.head()
                            T        date
date                                     
1990-01-01 00:00:00 -0.335715  1990-01-01
1990-01-01 00:00:00  0.867022  1990-01-01
1990-01-01 00:00:00 -0.503262  1990-01-01
1990-01-01 00:30:00 -0.543694  1990-01-01
1990-01-01 01:00:00  2.067549  1990-01-01
```

And your questions:

> First, how can I get the total number of occurrences of T for each month?

I'll assume your looking for the occurrences for each *year, month* combination.  You can use `.groupby()` for that:

```
>>> counts = df.groupby(by=[df.index.year, df.index.month])['T'].count()

>>> counts.head()
date  date
1990  1       3750
      2       3357
      3       3626
      4       3539
      5       3790
Name: T, dtype: int64

>>> counts.tail()
date  date
2017  8       3711
      9       3611
      10      3649
      11      3689
      12      3557
Name: T, dtype: int64
```

Note that `.count()` is the number of non-null observations.

> What is the way to plot those axes correctly and only have tick marks for years (not for the months)?

This is tricker, although mine is probably not the smartest solution.  (I think you should be able to use [`MonthFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12912408/7954504) as well.)

```
allyrs = counts.index.get_level_values(0)
uyrs = allyrs.unique()
mask = np.zeros_like(uyrs)
mask[1:] = np.where(allyrs[1:] != allyrs[:-1])[0]

counts.plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(mask, yrs)
plt.title('Obs. Count by Year/Month')
plt.xlabel('Year-Month')
plt.ylabel('Count')
```

Result:

[image]