# Date Label on XAxis of Scatter Plot

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.3

So I just installed Python3.3, Numpy, MySQL Connector, and Matplotlib.  I have a table with a lot of data where I wrote a query that outputs it to something similar to this:

```
Timestamp(unix)  Data(float)
1353000347       90.7000
1353007787       90.7000
1353015227       90.7000
1353000347       89.6899
1353007787       90.7000
1353015227       90.7000
```

So through a lot of trial and error and piecing together tutorials and other questions on here I ended up with this python script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mysql.connector

#Open DB Connection
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='db',
                              user='user',password='')
#Get Buffered Cursor
curA = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

curA.execute(
"""
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`),`data1`
   FROM `data`
"""
)

rows = np.array(curA.fetchall())
cnx.close()

x = rows[:,0]
y = rows[:,1]
plt.scatter(x,y,20,'r','o',None,None,None,None,0.05,0)
plt.show()
```

I have a lot of data points that will overlap (same coordinates) so I wanted the alpha real low.  I got what I wanted here:

[image]

Anyways, what I wanted was to simply format the tick markers to dates (e.g. Month, Year).  I searched a lot on this problem and found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498510/creating-graph-with-date-and-time-in-axis-labels-with-matplotlib), but I wasn't able to adapt it or make sense of how I could apply it to my script.  Seems overly complicated for such a simple thing?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but the basic approach I would suggest is to convert your timestamps -> `datetime` objects [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).  You can then plot directly against those objects.  You might still need to tweak the formatters a bit, but this should get you 80% of the way.

Comment: also see `pandas` which has a whole bunch of fancy semi-intelligent date formatting (but may be overkill and is another can of worms)

Comment: Actually, found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090383/plotting-unix-timestamps-in-matplotlib) shortly after which I think gives me what I need.

Comment: good.  As a style note, you should use kwags, not positional args to pass arguments to `scatter`, ex `scatter(x, y, s=20, color='r', marker='o', alpha=.5)` which is much more readable and (more) future proof.

Comment: Do you think this should be marked as a duplicate of that question?

Comment: @tcaswell Yes, probably.